# Alternative to simplification speed-up by replacing an integer with its "non-exact" counterpart

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions

This is a safe setting which assured that all of the equations I want to simplify are actually fully simplified:

```
SetSystemOptions[SimplificationOptions->AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables->100]
```

However, this setting also increases the calculation times of *some* equations, as in from a fraction of a second to minutes. The latter can be prevented by simply replacing one of the integer values within the equation with its real counterpart.

Example. This needs minutes:

```
Assuming[vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRm1 > 0 && bRm2 > 0 && bRis > 0 && bFx > bRm1 && bFx > bRm2 && bRis < (aRx*rho + vR0)^2/(2*bRm2) && (aRx*rho + bRm2*rho + vR0 - Sqrt[-2*bRis*bRm2 + (aRx*rho + vR0)^2])/bRm2 < (aRx*rho + bRm2*rho + vR0)/bRm2 && bRm1 < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && aRx < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && rho < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && rho < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && vR0 < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && bRis < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && aRx < ∞ && rho < ∞ && vR0 < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && bRis < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && aRx < ∞ && rho < ∞ && vR0 < ∞, Simplify[vF0/bFx >= (aRx*bRm1*rho + bRm1*bRm2*rho + bRm1*vR0 - bRm1*Sqrt[-2*bRis*bRm2 + (aRx*rho + vR0)^2] + bRm2*Sqrt[-2*bRis*bRm2 + (aRx*rho + vR0)^2])/(bRm1*bRm2)]]
```

so I replace the last `2` by `2.` to get an identical solution (apart from slight differences in form) in an instant:

```
Assuming[vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRm1 > 0 && bRm2 > 0 && bRis > 0 && bFx > bRm1 && bFx > bRm2 && bRis < (aRx*rho + vR0)^2/(2*bRm2) && (aRx*rho + bRm2*rho + vR0 - Sqrt[-2*bRis*bRm2 + (aRx*rho + vR0)^2])/bRm2 < (aRx*rho + bRm2*rho + vR0)/bRm2 && bRm1 < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && aRx < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && rho < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && rho < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && vR0 < ∞ && bRm1 < ∞ && bRis < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && aRx < ∞ && rho < ∞ && vR0 < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && bRis < ∞ && bRm2 < ∞ && aRx < ∞ && rho < ∞ && vR0 < ∞, Simplify[vF0/bFx >= (aRx*bRm1*rho + bRm1*bRm2*rho + bRm1*vR0 - bRm1*Sqrt[-2*bRis*bRm2 + (aRx*rho + vR0)^2] + bRm2*Sqrt[-2*bRis*bRm2 + (aRx*rho + vR0)^2.])/(bRm1*bRm2)]]
```

So far, it is fast, gives correct solutions but seems like a weird workaround. Question: Any alternative to that?

Comment: Hmm, the first time I tried the slow method, it took only a second. So I quit the kernel to time it, and now it's takeing minutes. I know `Simplify` caches previous results, but that could not be what was going on.

Comment: Well, I had it run fast once more on the first shot. Odd.  Adding the option `TimeConstraint -> 0.01` seems to consistently make it run as fast as the `2.` version.